# Save UITextField Data Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I got a UITextField as subview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(21, 21, 159, 37)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = @"name";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
textField.delegate = (id) self;
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(saveData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];

[self.view addSubview:textField];

}
```

---

```
-(void)saveData:(id)sender {

    NSString *savestring = textField.text; 
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savedstring"]; 
    [defaults synchronize];        
}
```

To load the data (viewDidLoad)

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
    NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"]; 
    [textField setText:loadstring];
```

Now the problem is that it doesn't save and load the text of the UITextField.

Comment: Are you saving the textfield as a property?

Comment: I have noticed that you are calling saveData:() method in textfield's 
UIControlEventEditingDidEnd event, is this event called properly?

Comment: As Samir said, check whether that event is getting called, if YES, then check whether `textField.text` contains any string value or its null.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enter some string in the Textfield and press return key, so that it will get a chance to call your "saveData" method and store the value in the NSUserDefaults. Just check all the values.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
textField.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"];
```

Thanks everyone for your answers

Comment: Seriously? You have already written the same line in your question.
This is not cool buddy.
And yeah may be you are assigning value of @"savedstring" before initilization of textfield.

Answer (score 0):

"addSubview" after this method write to load the data method...

```
[self.view addSubview:textField];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
 NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"]; 
 [textField setText:loadstring];
```